# TFS ConvertWorkspaceItem error

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, workflow-activity, build-server

I'm trying to get Uri path from Local path of Build directory. I've added ConvertWorkspaceItem however I get an error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is the way I've set it up. I get valid BuildDirectory (C:\builds...) and I want to get a server path (\TFSBUILDSrv\some\blah)

[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify valid variable names for all of these three properties. there should also be a variable declared in the workflow called workspace.

It's a type error
As [ConvertWorkspaceItem.Workspace Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.convertworkspaceitem.workspace(v=vs.120).aspx) from MSDN mentioned, this should be a value of workspace that contains the files to convert paths for( BuildDirectory to test1)

So just need to change the **variable type** to **workspace** of the workspace variable. Everything is OK.

A example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just as the update answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888350/tfs-2013-convert-server-path-to-local-path/34890636#34890636, your directions are wrong. So its a bit confusing

Comment: Man. You're the only person that responded to this. I guess not many people know TFS stuff. I should get into this business :)