# TFS 2013 convert server path to local path

Tags: tfsbuild, workflow-activity

How would I convert server path like "$/Test/BuildResources" to ex: "D:\test\etc.."

I'm running TFS 2013. Would I use "GetWorkspace" item?

When I try to use "GetWorkspace" and specify **"$/Test"** in the **Name** field I get an error message. Not sure if this is the way to do it.
thanks

**EDIT:**

This is what I tried.
This is my setup:

I'm trying to convert "$/IW_Xavier/Deployment" to local path
[image]
[image]

I also added GetWorkspace and set it up like this:
[image]
[image]

But it doesn't convert it:
[image]

I get an error message. I also tried using **"GetLocalPath"**-not sure if this does what I want but  it also doesn't work.

**EDIT 2:**

This is what I ended up doing:
1. Added the path in "Source Settings" 
[image]

2. Under "Process" tab I store a server path in a variable "DeploymentScript"
   [image]
3. Added "GetLocalPath" from the toolbox and used a variable for Output
   [image]

This worked for me. I get a local path (C:\blah\blah...) for "#\IT_dfj" etc
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to convert it. If you already know the server path,you can directly get the workspace by using this method [Workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.getlocalitemforserveritem(v=vs.120).aspx)

Please refer the answer from *Edward Thomson*  which including very detailed explanation about using TFS API to query  server and local path.

> If you have a given local path (in this case, your `SourcesDirectory`)
>   you can use that to read the workspace cache and get the information
>   you need for the server connection that the build server has created:
>
> ```
> // Get the workspace information for the build server's workspace
>  var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(sourcesDirectory);
>
> // Get the TFS Team Project Collection information from Edward Thomson  the workspace cache
> // information then load the TFS workspace itself.
>  var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.serverUri);
>  var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);
> ```
>
> Once you have a workspace, you can query it for the path mappings. It
>   will do the necessary translation from server to local path based on
>   your workspace mappings. For example:
>
> ```
> workspace.GetServerItemForLocalItem("D:\My\Local\Path");
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem("$/My/Server/Path");
> ```
>
> This mechanism will only work, however, if your build definition
>   actually sets up the workspace to include these files. If you need
>   some directory `$/Foo/Bar`, you will need to make sure that it is
>   included in the Source Settings details tab of the Build Definition.
>
> Source:
>   [How do I resolve the root and relative paths of TFS folders on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157538/how-do-i-resolve-the-root-and-relative-paths-of-tfs-folders-on-the-server)

Moreover, if you have to convert both, you can also use an [ConvertWorkspaceItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.convertworkspaceitem(v=vs.120).aspx) activity to achieve it.

And in "**GetWorkspace**"  activity for the **Name** field, you must **specify a workspace name**(such as `"MyWorkspace"` ) or a variable which get the workspace name.

[image]

---

**Updated**

Sorry for the misunderstanding, finally I got what you're doing.

First, The workspace only stand for this, so the get workspace and workspace name will return :FABRIKAM-1

[image]

And this is source control folder and local folder, this is a mapping Relationship. Of course this is in your dev machine.

[image]

However, you want to convert the server path to local path , want to get the path of MSTest file, but this is running on your **build agent**.  So you don't need to looking for it in your dev machine, you just need to looking for the path on build agent.

What you are looking for is still the **TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY** (The build agent working directory). Then add the Relative path such as `xx\..\..`. Just as this case said, [TFS How to GetEnvironmentVariable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867042/tfs-how-to-getenvironmentvariable-value/34895102?noredirect=1#comment57554769_34895102) . You can't get it directly through the custom process.

So .......the ultimate solution. Suggest you to run a [script in your build process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353(v=vs.120).aspx) or use the 2015 new build (vNext build), then everything should be OK. :)

Comment: Your answer works. However I found another solution. I used "GetLocalPath" item from the toolbox (I had to move it below Initialize environment). Please see edit above